# Why is typeid not compile-time constant like sizeof

Tags: c++

Why is typeid(someType) not constant like sizeof(someType) ?

This question came up because recently i tried something like:

```
template <class T>
class Foo
{
    static_assert(typeid(T)==typeid(Bar) || typeid(T)==typeid(FooBar));
};
```

And i am curious why the compiler knows the size of types (sizeof) at compile time, but not the type itself (typeid)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you are dealing with types, you'd rather use simple metaprogramming techniques:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
void Foo()
{
    static_assert((std::is_same<T, int>::value || std::is_same<T, double>::value));
}

int main()
{
    Foo<int>();
    Foo<float>();
}
```

where `is_same` could be implemented like this:

```
template <class A, class B>
struct is_same
{
    static const bool value = false;
};

template <class A>
struct is_same<A, A>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};
```

`typeid` probably isn't compile-time because it has to deal with runtime polymorphic objects, and that is where you'd rather use it (if at all).

Comment: BTW, `is_same` is a part of Standard library since C++11, as well as `static_assert`.

Answer (score 5):

C++ can handle constant (compile-time) expressions of some types, but reference types are not among those types.  The result of a `typeid` expression is a reference to a `std::type_info` object.

Apparently for a while in 2008, the C++ standard committee had `typeid` expressions such as the ones in your example behaving as constant expressions, just like `sizeof`. However, according to [this comment](http://cxxpanel.org.uk/ballotcomment/251), that change was ultimately reverted.

Comment: the link to comment is dead!

Comment: i want to create a template of std::type_index or something that uniquely identifies a class. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Because typeid requires RTTI, i.e, typeid is performed at runtime and BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT is performed at compile time.

More information [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/typeinfo/type_info/).

Comment: except smerlin was asking about a particular use of typeid, and this particular use of typeid does not do runtime lookup

Comment: I disagree, his question: "Why is typeid(someType) not constant like sizeof(someType) ?", and not about a particular use of typeid

Comment: Coelhudo, the "particular use" is the one in which the argument is a *type*. RTTI is only used when the argument is an object expression.

Comment: And then RTTI is also only used if the object expression is of polymorphic type. In other words, `pair<int, int> p; typeid(p);` does not need RTTI.

Answer (score 1):

Because `typeid` has the flexibility to do lookups at runtime based on a pointer or reference to an object, it can't return a compile-time constant. Even when it looks like it could. `sizeof` has no such restrictions, as it always does its calculation at compile time.

Comment: except smerlin was asking about a particular use of typeid, and this particular use of type id does _not_ do runtime lookup.

Comment: Runtime constants are generally limited to integer values. `typeid` returns a reference to a `type_info` class, which is much more than that.

Comment: Ah i forgot that typeid works for objects aswell ... still i think it would be very useful if something like the example above could be done with it.
Hopefully C++0x supports something like that.
Well at least it will support static asserts...

Answer (score 0):

It knows the type itself (in its own internal language) at compile time, but not its type id (which has clearly been created for runtime).