# Can class name be referenced implicitly at compile-time?

Tags: c++, templates, class-names

**Is there a way to implicitly reference a class' name at compile-time?**

Specifically, if I want to declare an instance of `template class A` using `class B` from within the scope of `class B`, is there a way to avoid explicit reference to "B" in the syntax to declare the `class A` instance?

To better-illustrate with an example:

```
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
  typedef void (T::*TFunc)();

  A( T& t ) : t_( t ) {}

  void callFunc( TFunc tFunc ) { (t_.*tFunc)(); }

private:
  T& t_;
};

class LongClassName
{
public:
  LongClassName() : a_( *this ) {}

  void pubFunc()
  {
    a_.callFunc( &LongClassName::privFunc ); // Can I avoid explicitly using "LongClassName" here?
  }

private:
  void privFunc() { cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; }

  A<LongClassName> a_; // Can I avoid explicitly using "LongClassName" here?
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  LongClassName().pubFunc();
  return 0;
}
```

What I've tried:
Read [Is there a __CLASS__ macro in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666802/is-there-a-class-macro-in-c), so I'm aware there's no `__CLASS__` (pseudo-equivalent to `__FUNCTION__`) preprocessor macro. Some of the solutions to that post extract the class name from `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` - but that is a runtime solution not applicable to this situation.

I've read [conflicting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781832/does-typeidt-get-evaluated-at-run-time-or-compile-time) [information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981413/why-is-typeid-not-compile-time-constant-like-sizeof) on StackOverflow about whether `typeid(T)` is run time or compile time; either way, `A<typeid(*this).name()> a_;` doesn't compile, and looks wrong anyhow: there's obviously no `this` in that context.
By my reading, the text at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid makes clear that `typeid` is runtime, and so not-applicable to this situation.

Comment: are you worried about too much typing or is there a real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 - academic curiosity: it seems like it'd be "nice"/less code-hazardous to be able to refer to the class name implicitly.

Comment: You could use `decltype(*this)` since that operates at compile time but as you said there is no `this` in that context

Comment: `decltype()` is probably more like what you'd need, not `typeid()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to avoid using the type name in `LongClassName::privFunc` and `A<LongClassName> a_;`.

That said, you can still make your life easier.  You can make an alias for `LongClassName` that you can use it it's place.  Adding

```
using LCN = LongClassName;
```

will let you use `LCN` in place of `LongClassName`

Answer (score 4):

You can declare local alias template with redefined default parameter to avoid using class name in second case:

```
template<typename T = LongClassName> using
A = ::A<T>;
A<> a_; // Can I avoid explicitly using "LongClassName" here?
```

As for shorter name for LongClassName, there is a common convention to declare corresponding type alias with a common name. It will also be helpful for writing copy / move constructors, etc:

```
class LongClassName
{
public:
  using Self = LongClassName;

  LongClassName() : a_( *this ) {}

  LongClassName(Self const &); // copy constructor

  Self & operator =(Self const &); // copy assignment operator

  void pubFunc()
  {
    a_.callFunc( &Self::privFunc ); // Can I avoid explicitly using "LongClassName" here?
  }

private:
  void privFunc() { cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; }

  A<Self > a_; // Can I avoid explicitly using "LongClassName" here?
};
```

Comment: That's a clever way to approach this, and seems like a good convention - only one explicit reference to the class name, and has easy readability everywhere else.

Comment: Would you use `Self` if the class name were short (for consistency with cases when it is long)? In other words, is it a good practice to use `Self` instead of a class name in general?

Comment: @Evg Yes, I typically always declare this alias. Note that it is useable even if class name is not that long. For example it makes it possible to quickly locate copy / move constructors or member function pointers using normal search and simplifies refactoring. I think that there was even a proposal to add into language some sort of built-in identifier (in addition to `this`) for this purpose.

Comment: Will use it, too. Thanks! Just another question: are there any use cases for the public member type? Should it be `public` or `private`?

Comment: This isn't what I'd call common practice in C++ programs.  I've used it, with the same `Self` naming convention.  I also use `using Super = MyBaseClass;` (Object Pascal influence).